# Python TypeError issue 'int' not iterable using list with chain

Tags: python, arrays

I'm running into an odd error in Python. I am using the `chain` command to flatten out an array of data and then the `list` command to put it back into an array. However, depending on how I define the array, it gives me an error. What I would like is something like this

```
import os, io, struct, array
from itertools import chain


#Open file and set the size of the data for use later
file=open('filePath','rb')
size = os.fstat(file.fileno()).st_size
count = int(size)

#Initializing an array with length to match the data
dataArray=[0]*count


#storing the values of data 4 bytes at a time to produce the numeric values. 
for i in range(0,count,4):
    dataArray[i]=struct.unpack('i', file.read(4))

#Deals with a tuple issue ((x,),(y,),...) -> (x,y,...)
dataArray = list(chain(*dataArray[:count]))
```

This gives me `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` from that last line. However, if I say something like

```
count = 33638664
myarray=[0]*count


for i in range(3638664):
    myarray[i]=struct.unpack('i', file.read(4))


result = list(chain(*myarray[:3638664]))
```

I receive no such error. Notice that in this second piece of code, the value in the chain method, 3638664, is smaller than `count`. It will produce an error if I set it to length `count`. Is this some sort of indexing or counting issue? I'm not sure why I am getting this kind of error for my original code and not for this arbitrary `count` value code.

Comment: This needs a [mcve]. As it is, both versions of the code throw the same error for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unpacking `dataArray` with `*dataArray[:count]`. This causes `chain` to try to iterate over each element of `dataArray`, but it can't, because (as the error says), it can't iterate over an integer. So, when it hits an element of `dataArray` that's an int instead of a tuple, it breaks.

You're also doing some very weird stuff with the initial loop to read in the file. There's no reason to preinitialize the list like that. You can just do this, and it'll do the same thing. I also don't understand why you're truncating to `count` length, when at most, there's `count/4` entries.

```
import os, io, struct, array
from itertools import chain


#Open file and set the size of the data for use later
file = open('file','rb')
size = os.fstat(file.fileno()).st_size
count = int(size)
data_array = [struct.unpack('i', file.read(4)) for _ in range(0,count,4)]

#Deals with a tuple issue ((x,),(y,),...) -> (x,y,...)
data_array = list(chain(*data_array))
print(data_array)
```

There's also no good reason to use `chain` here. Your format string for `struct.unpack` will always return one item, so you can just do `dataArray = [struct.unpack('i', file.read(4))[0] for _ in range(0,count,4)]`.

You should also be using `with` to do file handling.

Finally, there's no reason to do `count = int(size)`. `size` is already an int. So, the final simplified code would look like this:

```
import os
import struct

with open('file','rb') as file:
    size = os.fstat(file.fileno()).st_size
    dataArray = [struct.unpack('i', file.read(4))[0] for _ in range(0,size,4)]
print(dataArray)
```

Comment: @user99264 Great, glad I could help!